# ext4 & jbd2 dirty metadata

Tags: ext4, journaling

I have an embedded system based on the RiotBoard, I have the main file system on the MMC set as read-only, and an 8gb usb flash drive for writeable storage.  rootfs is debian, linux kernel version 4.3.0-rc2-00019-gbcee19f

Drive format commands are
`mkfs.ext4 -U 2d4d3021-ebaf-4e29-b0e4-e8068d3bd237 /dev/sda1
tune2fs /dev/sda1 -i 0  //Don't check against time clock
tune2fs /dev/sda1 -c 1  //Check every time`

and the FSTAB line

```
UUID=2d4d3021-ebaf-4e29-b0e4-e8068d3bd237 /mnt/USB1 ext4 data=journal,nofail 0 2
```

I keep getting this error

> JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sda1, blocknr = 1087488). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.

with blocknr incrementing every time.  This happens whether or not it is an unplanned power off, or reboot from the command line.  I am a bit dubious that this drive has a real problem, it is a new sandisk brand drive.

**Edit 1:**
Reformatting drive fixes this problem, so I am not clear why FSCKFIX=yes in /etc/default/rcS is not fixing this. The output of e2fsck was

```
Checking file systems...fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1 has been mounted 1 times without being checked, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (1886088, counted=1886055).
Fix? yes
/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda1: 57/488640 files (17.5% non-contiguous), 68117/1954172 blocks
fsck died with exit status 1
***skipped lines here***
JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sda1, blocknr = 1084928). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
```

Comment: So a manual FSCK does not fix the issue? I have a system with the same, I will report back if I solve it.